# pandas dataframe won't reorder columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, quandl

I'm working on a script to retreive data from Quandl which manipulates the data before saving. I'm stuck on 1 step which is id like to reorder my columns using pandas like `df = df[['Code','Date','Open','High','Low','Close','Volume']]` or in simpler terms, swap date with Code

I thought this was because the system is auto setting Date as an index, however the traceback says `['Date'] not in index`

I have observed that the date label drops out of the dataframe when `df.index = df.index.strftime('%Y%m%d')`, Print 2 output. If I comment this line out the error code persists.

I tried inserting `df.set_index('Code')` to see if changing the index would help but did not.

Does anyone know what the issue is here?

**Code**

```
myArr = ['CHRIS/CME_AD1']
cDate=int(time.strftime("%Y%m%d"))

# get quandl data, edit dataframe & save to csv
for qCode in myArr:
    data = qdl.get(qCode, start_date=StartDate)
    df = pd.DataFrame(data)
 #   df.to_dict()
    qID=(str(qCode[qCode.find('/')+1:]))
    print(df)

# format data & save
    df.insert(loc=0, column='Code', value=qID)
    df=df.drop(columns=['Change','Settle','Previous Day Open Interest'])
    df.rename(columns={'Last':'Close'}, inplace=True)  
    df.index = df.index.strftime('%Y%m%d')
    print(df) 
    df = df[['Code','Date','Open','High','Low','Close','Volume']] #reorder columns
    df.to_csv(path + qID + '_' + str(cDate) + '.txt', sep=',', index=True, header=1) 
print('Quandl Download Complete')
```

**Traceback**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "\\progsql\SQL\Script\Python\EOD_Quandl - Copy.py", line 29, in <module>
    df = df[['Code','Date','Open','High','Low','Close','Volume']] #reorder columns
  File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 2679, in __getitem__
    return self._getitem_array(key)
  File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 2723, in _getitem_array
    indexer = self.loc._convert_to_indexer(key, axis=1)
  File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py", line 1327, in _convert_to_indexer
    .format(mask=objarr[mask]))
KeyError: "['Date'] not in index"
```

**Print 1 - from Quandl**

```
              Open             ...              Previous Day Open Interest
Date                           ...                                        
2018-05-10  0.7460             ...                                159970.0
2018-05-11  0.7534             ...                                164459.0
2018-05-14  0.7543             ...                                167173.0
2018-05-15  0.7526             ...                                169622.0
2018-05-16  0.7473             ...                                170863.0
2018-05-17  0.7516             ...                                164165.0
2018-05-18  0.7513             ...                                164628.0
2018-05-21  0.7529             ...                                161673.0
2018-05-22  0.7586             ...                                147136.0
2018-05-23  0.7575             ...                                147454.0
2018-05-24  0.7568             ...                                153308.0
2018-05-25  0.7578             ...                               151199.0

[12 rows x 8 columns]
```

**Print 2 - post manipulation**

```
             Code    Open    High     Low   Close    Volume
20180510  CME_AD1  0.7460  0.7540  0.7455  0.7534  125257.0
20180511  CME_AD1  0.7534  0.7567  0.7522  0.7538   93512.0
20180514  CME_AD1  0.7543  0.7565  0.7525  0.7529   72806.0
20180515  CME_AD1  0.7526  0.7538  0.7449  0.7471  129077.0
20180516  CME_AD1  0.7473  0.7524  0.7448  0.7514  125867.0
20180517  CME_AD1  0.7516  0.7548  0.7498  0.7509  108841.0
20180518  CME_AD1  0.7513  0.7529  0.7489  0.7511   87656.0
20180521  CME_AD1  0.7529  0.7588  0.7504  0.7583  118843.0
20180522  CME_AD1  0.7586  0.7607  0.7567  0.7576  104227.0
20180523  CME_AD1  0.7575  0.7584  0.7523  0.7558  149203.0
20180524  CME_AD1  0.7568  0.7584  0.7543  0.7579  102328.0
20180525  CME_AD1  0.7578  0.7591  0.7543  0.7549   85082.0
```

Comment: Maybe this is just how pandas outputs, but it looks like it's saying that the string representation of a list containing the word date is not in the index.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I spent some time working on solutions with `pd.Dataframe.set_index` and `pd.Dataframe.reset_index` but the original index kept persisting.

Since the index cannot be treated as a column and the df must have an index I came up with the idea to:
- renaming the index 
- copying it to a column
- reorder column
- save `to_csv` with `index=False`

It a little long winded but achieve the task in this case.

```
# format data & save  
    df.index.names = ['ID']
    df['Date'] = df.index
    df.insert(loc=0, column='Code', value=qID)
    df=df.drop(columns=['Change','Settle','Previous Day Open Interest'])
    df.rename(columns={'Last':'Close'}, inplace=True)  
    df.index = df.index.strftime('%Y%m%d')
    df = df[['Code','Date','Open','High','Low','Close','Volume']] #reorder columns
    df.to_csv(path + qID + '_' + str(cDate) + '.txt', sep=',', index=False, header=0) 

    print(df)
```

Answer (score 0):

'Date' there is the name of the index of your dataframe, not one of the columns, so you cannot "reorder" it together with the other columns.

Comment: My thinking was to make Date a column with df.set_index('Code'). This didn't work, I suspect because the values are not unique. I'm going to work on creating an index and ensuring Date is a column instead.